# Navigation controller not working

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation based templete in which we get default file appdelegate.h,.m file and rootviewcontroller.h and.m file. Now i have required in project that rootviewcontroller will show only first time when application install in device. And in rootviewcontroller i have button o click event of that i add new view as subview. And on New view i have a button which further proceed a new view. To proceed new view i have use [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:new_view1 animated:YES] but this is not working. Means not pushing view. How i fix it?

In appdelegate file i use this code for didfinish launch:-

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

  }
```

and on button click of rootviewcontroller i use this code:-

```
- (void)parser{
    main_view_obj=[[Home_Screen_viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home_Screen_viewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:main_view_obj.view];

}
```

end on button clikc of mainview i use this code:-

```
 -(IBAction)accounts{
    [appDelegate startProgressBar:@"while loading data..."];
    account_view =[[Account_login_viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Account_login_viewController" bundle:Nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:account_view animated:YES ];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    [appDelegate endProgressBar];

}
```

Now problem is that  [self.navigationController pushViewController:account_view animated:YES ] not working. How fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work

```
-(IBAction)accounts{
        [appDelegate startProgressBar:@"while loading data..."];
        account_view =[[Account_login_viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Account_login_viewController" bundle:Nil];
        [appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:account_view animated:YES ];
        appDelegate.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
        [appDelegate endProgressBar];

    }
```

Comment: put an action for bacbarbutton item. currently it's nil.